# What's the correct webhook for Stripe 5.2 extension?

Tags: drupal, stripe

I can't find any documentation for the latest Stripe 5.2 extension and I've setup the webhook as 'https://www.example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/1' - I have setup Stripe as the only payment processor hence the '1' at the end.  Is this correct?
Using Civi 5.7.3 and Drupl 7.61

Comment: When you click the edit link to edit the payment processor at /civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor, look at the url and one of the parameters in it is "id=". What's the number after the equals sign? That's the id.

Comment: ipn is set to 1 but it's working now - the problem was (oddly) didn't work in Chrome but worked in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, The new webhook url should be https://www.example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/1 where 1 is the payment processor ID.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've set it to but it's not working - just sits there.  Do you know if you have to start with a test submission first with Stripe?  I'm trying with a live submission.  Andy

Comment: I am still using this format https://example.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/xx and it seems to still work. Can we get the docs updated?

Comment: @AndyClark can you make sure the ID i.e 1 you are using is correct and belong to right payment processor ID?

Comment: Yes, the id is correct and now working.  The problem was that for some reason Chrome wasn't showing the confirmation screen, but Firefox did. So not a Stripe extension problem at all.  But the docs link for Stripe 5.2 extension in github isn't working so hard to find accurate info for an extension that has changed recently

Comment: So can we mark this as Answered so that it can be helpful for other users?

Comment: does this answer cover WordPress as well as Drupal?